# Accessing JSP variable inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have the following JS block and i'm trying to move it into my jQuery scope and the $(document).ready() block. I have tried a few things, not sure how to achieve it.

```
function access(){
    <% String str=request.getHeader("REMOTE_USER"); %>
    var s="<%=str%>";
    getUserData(s);
}
```

Comment: JSP code is server-side code; jQuery is client-side code.

Comment: But isn't JS also client side code? I am able to access JSP variables inside Javascript.

Comment: Not really. The JSP runs on the server, and then the *output* of that is sent as an HTTP response to the browser. In the browser, all you've got is what's left from the JSP processing.

Comment: As has Pointy already written, the key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser) and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

Comment: Anyway, the first two lines of your code in the `access()` function should work, generating actually just one line of JS code. The rest depends on what `getUserData()` actually is - if it is some JS function, it should work. If it is a Java method you want to call, you should look for AJAX.